# Zip up source code and store it in specfic location from makefile

Tags: c, makefile, zip

I run a model for which I occasionally have to change the source code. I would like to have a provision within the makefile which automatically zips up all the source files associated with a particular run and stores them along with the output files. Is it possible to do this from within the makefile?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an ad hoc version control system. Perhaps you should use a real one like Git, Subversion, or CVS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [John's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061356/zip-up-source-code-and-store-it-in-specfic-location-from-makefile/13061427#comment17739685_13061356). But this is a piece of cake to do in a Makefile:

```
ARCHIVE = src.tar.gz

$(ARCHIVE): $(C_FILES)
    tar cvzf $(ARCHIVE) $(C_FILES)
```

You can adapt this to do it however you'd like.